# How to convert data frame column to string to perform ner_chunks

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

How to convert dataframe column to string.

Abstract column consists of title description data

I want dataframe column abstract to convert to string so that i can provide as a input for nerchunks

please note my title and abstract column of a dataframe is of object type only.

```
df['Abstract'] = df['Abstract'].astype(str)
df['Abstract'].head(5)




i = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(nltk.pos_tag_sents(word_tokenize(df['Abstract'])) , binary=True)
[a for a in i if len(a) == 1]
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

To get columns of a dataframe, you can try

```
df.columns
```

But you are looking for a string which would contain all column names, and df.column returns dtype object. So you first convert abouve into list, and simply join them to result into a string. Here you go:

```
yourResult = ' '.join(list(dataset.columns))
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but column data is not displaying

Comment: Can i have a look at your dataset? What data is being displayed? Maybe post it on gist ,and i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

your are passing wrong input in word_tokenize method, you need to pass string and you are passing pandas series

```
# example
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['how are you', 'i am fine', 'what about others'], columns= ['msg']))
```

now when i pass df['msg'] to word_tokenize i.e word_tokenize(df['msg']) it will throw same error that you r receiving,
Instead you should pass string

```
print([word_tokenize(x) for x in df['msg']])
#o/p
[['how', 'are', 'you'], ['i', 'am', 'fine'], ['what', 'about', 'others']]
```

hope this will help you